# ajax call not performed in firefox when form submits

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. The following snippet works fine in Chrome but not in Firefox. The odd thing is, if I test in Firefox and add a breakpoint, e.g. at "request.send(params)" and do a "Step Over" everything works fine. But if I perform a "Continue" it also wont work.

Does anybody know, what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var form =$("form#my_form"); 
    var id = form.id;
   form.submit(function(event){ 
      event.preventDefault();      
    myVar.myMethod(document.getElementById('my_input_1').value, document.getElementById('my_input_2').value);

     this.submit();
   });
});


var myVar = {};

myVar.myMethod = function(par1, par2) {
    params = "par1=" + par1 + "&par2=" + par2;
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "Destination", true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    request.send(params);
};
```

Comment: is `this.submit();` needed there? you already send the data via `myMethod()`. I am afraid that calling `this.submit` will trigger another submit...

Comment: not to mention that using `this.submit()` will bypass the jQuery submit handler and use default browser process

Comment: Ah thanks guys. I removed the this.submit() and now everything works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it's working in Chrome - could just be a speed thing.

Sounds like your ajax request (being asynchronous) isn't getting sent before this.submit(); You need to write some kind of callback in `myVar.myMethod` that only processes once the XHR is finished.

A better method might be (since you're using jQuery, but not really utilizing it):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var form =$("form#my_form"); 
    var id = form.id;
    form.submit(function(event){ 
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post({
            url: '??', // from form - the url you submitted to
            data: {par1: $('#my_input_1').val(), par2: $('#my_input_2').val() }
            success: function( data ) {
                //handle the returned data
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Or, if you're trying to submit those two fields in the POST data to your form's url attribute, you should just process the POST data when you get it on the next page - in other words, as long as your inputs are in the form they should be sent to the url with POST.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the this.submit()-Line and now everything works fine. Thanks to David Votrubec's and charlietfl comments, which brings me on the track.

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
    var form =$("form#my_form"); 
    var id = form.id;
   form.submit(function(event){ 
      event.preventDefault();      
    myVar.myMethod(document.getElementById('my_input_1').value, document.getElementById('my_input_2').value);
   });
});


var myVar = {};

myVar.myMethod = function(par1, par2) {
    params = "par1=" + par1 + "&par2=" + par2;
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "Destination", true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    request.send(params);
};
```